# Can element be a parent of a control?

Tags: sapui5

In a scenario, a parent of a control is responsible for performing & parsing data requests. However, it has no real DOM; the parsed data is for it's children only.

For the parent, one could use `core.Control` and do a simple render wrap around the children, but my question is, can `core.Element` be used for the parent & skip the unneeded render step for it, while still rendering its children?

In theory, both are `ManagedObject`s, so nothing stops me from doing this. I find no reference on somehow populating a static `renderer` prop on an `core.Element` however, nor any info on what "[can have associated DOM](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Element)" means.

Ideally, the managed aggregation chain should look like this:

`sap.m.Page::content` ->  `my.Element::elementChildren` -> `my.Control`

Thanks

Comment: Would be interesting to see the bigger picture. At the moment I don't understand any of this.